# Uniform finite dimensional approximation of continuous function sequence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $x_n$ be the continuous  function on $[0, 1]$ that is $1$ at $2^{-n}$ and $0$ outside $[2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n+1}]$. For an arbitrarily given $\epsilon >0$, is there a finite dimensional subspace $V$ of $C([0, 1])$ such that the distance from $x_n$ to $V$ is $<\epsilon$ for all $n$?

Comment: "The" continuous function? There are many continuous functions which satisfy that property. Also, what is the norm you are taking on $C([0,1])$?

Comment: Homeworks are not welcome here. Voting to close (How do I know it is a homework? Well, this is a very artificial problem with many standard features of textbook exercises...). What makes it somewhat funny though is that the OP never mentioned that $x_n$ are uniformly bounded (it does not follow from the other conditions, so Nate's solution, as written, would get only 6 points out of 10 if I were teaching the course :-) On the other hand, the division by the norm is an old trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Note first that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|x_n - x_m\| = 1$ for all $n \ne m$.

Suppose there were, so that for each $n$ there is $y_n \in V$ with $\|x_n - y_n\| < \epsilon$.  Let's say $\epsilon < 1/3$.  Then $\|y_n\| < 4/3$ for all $n$, and $$\|y_n - y_m\| \ge \|x_n - x_m\| - \|y_n - x_n\| - \|y_m - x_m\| \ge 1/3$$ for all $n \ne m$.  In particular, the sequence $y_n$ has no convergent subsequence.  But since $V$ is finite dimensional, the closed ball of $V$ with radius $4/3$ is compact, so this is absurd.